# How to set name in command line when running `aws ec2 run-instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

How to give `Name` in command line when running  `aws ec2 run-instances` ?

I don't find it in the [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The **Name** that's displayed there is taken from the *Name tag*. To set the instance name e.g. to `test01` and its volume name to `test01-disk1` you'd run something like this:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --tag-specifications \
    'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=test01}]' \
    'ResourceType=volume,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=test01-disk1}]' \
    ... other parameters ...
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Install `jq`

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resources \
  `aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-8f50120g --instance-type t2.small \
  --subnet-id subnet-xxxxxxx --security-group-ids sg-xxxxxxxx --key-name "MyKey" \
  | jq -r ".Instances[0].InstanceId"` \
  --tags "Key=Name,Value=development"
```